# Loading TomTom Multinet with shp2pgsql accented characters

Tags: encoding, shp2pgsql

I am tasked with loading a new set of TomTom multinet shape files into a Postgres database using a bespoke tool for the process.  The source data is supposedly in UTF-8.

I have just realised that some of the French data has been loaded and has had accented characters mangled, and the same for Spanish data (I presume the same is true of any accented data).

I have access to the C# code, and it creates batch files to run shp2pgsql like this;

```
{binpath}\shp2pgsql.exe" -s 4326 -d -D -I -g geom -W Latin1 "{datapath}\fraf24___________gc.shp" fraf24.gc | "{binpath}\psql.exe" -d Test -U postgres
```

I have confirmed that shp2pgsql.exe is outputting these mangled characters by redirecting output to a text file.

As I understood it, the -W option controlled the encoding, but whatever I have used, from not using -W at all to specifying Latin1, LATIN1, UTF-8; the output every time has been garbled accented characters such as these:

- "Rue de la RÃ©publique"
- "Rue de la BÃ©casse"

In other respects the loads seem to have gone well, so I am at a loss to explain what is going on, especially as it sounds like the -W option should be the solution?